# How to use "tee" with "source" command in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, tee

On Linux I'm using "**tee**" to capture the output of "**source**" command and print it to output log file, but failed. The command I'm using is like this:

```
source ./my_run.sh 2>&1 | tee -i my_run_log
```

The intention of *my_run.sh* is to "*make*" some compile job, as well as some routine jobs like *cd*, *rm* and *svn update*. The content of *my_run.sh* is like follows:

```
  make clean
  cd ..
  rm ./xxx
  svn up -r 166
  cd ./aaa/
  sed -i -e ......
  make compile
  make run
```

However, when I run it the "**tee**" just does NOT work, and do NOT give me the log file at all. In order to verify that the entire environment is good, I did a simpler test with:

```
ll 2>&1 | tee -i log
```

and in this simpler scenario the "**tee**" works perfectly fine and prints out "log" as I expected.
Can anyone help me find out where my problem is?
btw,
I'm working on **Red Hat Linux** (Release 5.9), using **bash shell**.
Thanks in advance!

**SOME MORE COMMENTS:**
I did some more tests and found that as long as the *my_run.sh* script has got "*make xxx*" stuffs in it, then "**tee**" will fail. **Seems like tee does NOT like make.** Any solutions?

Comment: Where are you looking for `my_run_log` afterwards?

Comment: Hard to say ... all I can say is "It works for me"

Comment: @tink I tried some more combinations and found that, if there're "make xxx" stuffs in the shell, then my "tee" would fail; if shell does NOT have "make xxx", then "tee" works fine. Seems "tee" does NOT like "make"?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm looking for the log file at the current directory where I "source" the script. At least for the simpler "ll 2>&1 | tee -i log" the output log file is located here.

Comment: @katyusza and you're saying that there is no such log file at all at all? Not even an empty one? Does `make clean` delete it by any chance?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes!! You're right!! The log output was deleted in the **make clean** process!! After fixing the *clean* stuff in the makefile everything is good! Looooooooooooooove you buddy!!

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Don't add them to the question. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @jww OK, will do, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @thatotherguy : We now learned that *make* deleted *my_run_log* while `tee` was writing to it. While this solved the problem, I wonder: Shouldn't `tee`    then output an error message - kind of "writing to stale file handle" or something? After all it still tries to write to a file, but the file doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Unrelated, but running `source` as the first command of a pipeline somewhat defeats the purpose of using `source` in the first place.

Comment: @user1934428 no, this is a common and useful thing to do for e.g. temp files. The file object itself still exists and works perfectly, it just has one less filename pointing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved; many thanks goes to @thatotherguy in leading me to the solution. The log output was actually deleted by the **make clean** process. After fixing the **clean** stuff in the *makefile*, everything is good.